# Swagger UI - OAuth2 client credential: basic/request body dropdown

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui

What controls the dropdown in the following screenshot?

[image: Swagger UI]

I'd like for it to just show the "Basic auth" choice with the respective client ID/secret input boxes.

Here's my config for Swashbuckle.AspnetCore (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore):

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
{
    Type = "oauth2",
    Flow = "application",
    TokenUrl = "https://localhost:44300/oauth/token"
}
```

[image: Swagger UI 2]